# Relating a class to its self

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a class `Revision`, `Revision` has the following definition:

```
class Revision(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Unicode, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Unicode)
```

In addition, each `Revision` *can* have an ancestor, as in a relationship to another `Revision`. Each `Revision` should also keep track of any successors, that is `Revision`s that have it as their ancestors. I have attempted both the following:

```
ancestorId = db.Column(db.Unicode, db.ForeignKey("revision.id"))
successors = db.relationship("Revision", backref="ancestor", lazy="dynamic")
```

which threw:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Revision.successors and back-reference Revision.ancestor are both of the same direction <symbol 'ONETOMANY>.  Did you mean to set remote_side on the many-to-one side ?
```

and

```
successors = db.relationship("Revision", backref="ancestor", lazy="dynamic")
```

which threw:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Revision.successors.  Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.  If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called [*adjacency list*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships). SQLAlchemy has an [example](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/examples/adjacency_list/adjacency_list.py) in its examples directory. The important part is `remote_side` argument for backref:

```
ancestorId = db.Column(db.Unicode, db.ForeignKey(id))
successors = db.relationship("Revision",
                             backref=db.backref("ancestor", remote_side=id),
                             lazy="dynamic")
```